# c++ vector is slower than my dynamic array?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I've written my own dynamic array. it's not complete and I've written that as a practice.
But when I finished the add function I wanted to test the performance of my own dynamic array class, and I saw some strange results. My dynamic array was a lot faster than the stl's vector. It was alomost 7 times faster!

here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class DynArray
{
public:
    DynArray()
    {
        arr = new T[2];
        capacity = 2;
        size = 0;
    }
    void Add(T value)
    {
        if(size < capacity)
        {
            arr[size++] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            T* tempArr = arr;
            arr = new T[capacity*2];
            memcpy(arr,tempArr,capacity*sizeof(T));
            capacity = capacity*2;
            delete[] tempArr;
            arr[size++] = value;
        }
    }

    int GetCapacity()
    {
        return capacity;
    }

    T operator [] (int index)
    {
        return arr[index];
    }
    ~DynArray()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }
private:
    T* arr;
    int capacity;
    int size;
};

void main()
{
    int c;
    cin >> c;
    DynArray<int> d;
    int a = GetTickCount();

    for(int i = 0;i < c;i++)
        d.Add(i);

    cout << "\n" << GetTickCount() - a << "\n\n";

    vector<int> v;

    a = GetTickCount();

    for(int i = 0;i < c;i++)
        v.push_back(i);


    cout << "\n" << GetTickCount() - a << '\n';
    cout << d.GetCapacity() << ',' << v.capacity() << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

I wonder why my dynamic array is faster? For example it takes around 1000ms to add one million items to the vector while it is less than 150ms with my dynamic array!

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Do not review the code. It was just some practicing. I just wanted to know why it was faster than vector.

Comment: Study the source code of your `<vector>` header. On my Linux system, it is in `/usr/include/c++/4.8/vector` and it includes several files from `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/` ...

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Have you compiled with optimization turned on? That is essential for generating efficient STL code.

Comment: Perhaps because your dynamic array includes a fraction of the functionality of a standard library vector?

Comment: Be aware that `vector` has some "better" behavior than your version. For example it works with non-trivial types (calling a copy or move constructor when resizing) and `push_back` gives a strong exception guarantee. These better behaviors cost extra code that *in theory* could be optimized away for a `vector<int>` in release mode, but it's worth looking into whether that actually happens in your test.

Comment: note that new T[] calls default ctor for each array element, then your memcpy overwrites all those elements without calling dtors for them. Also delete[] will call dtor on each just copied with memcpy objects, complete mess....

Comment: @marcin_j You are right about the ctor. But for deleting the tempArr if you look at vector you'll see that it also calls destructors when it needs to reallocate data because creating a new array and deleting the previous one is the only way to re-allocate an array. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @KooKoo you are right, std::vector will call destructors on previous array elements, but only after safely moving them to new array.

Comment: @marcin_j Yes you are right. and that is why I shouldn't use memcpy and use copy constructor instead. Am I right?

Comment: @KooKoo yes, you might want to check `std::copy`, it should copy objects using class operator=, and for trivial objects use memmove/memcpy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because your array is broken. You are moving the content with memcpy() which bypasses operator=. Also, your measurement is largely invalid; to get an accurate comparison, you need to perform the operation repeatedly and divide to get an average time (and do it with enough iterations to ignore any noise). Also, to compare accurately, you need to compile/link against the optimized version (there may be a debug version that is intentionally slower but provides additional checks, which you might be using inadvertently).

Comment: Thank you very much. I compiled against the optimized version and they are on par now.

Comment: Indeed, if I compile this with g++ `-O3` the factor is 1.5 advantage of `DynArray`, even though it's cheating.

Comment: @KooKoo your implementation looks fine for POD like types, ie. `struct A { int a; }` or as in your example `int`, I am not expert here but I suppose vector implementations does specialize for such types and actually maybe even perfom memcpy for them.